# Simple way to build an interface for a JSON response?

Tags: php, json

I am mostly a backend guy and was assigned a task for a school project to build a simple interface out of a JSON object. Preferable a table that displays two nested values coming back from the JSON. Is there any easy way to build this with a GUI tool? The output can be in PHP or JS.

Thank you

Comment: How complicated does this need to be. `$obj = json_decode($json);` will take a JSON string and turn it into a PHP object, and then [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) usually outputs objects neatly ([for example](http://ideone.com/hrggPU)).

Comment: I've read the post a couple of times, but your project specifications are very unclear to me.

Comment: if you're going to receive a json response from a server, then you have to build the markup on the clients side, you could use like `underscoreJs` or others for templating, this is too broad anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is unclear, but I think you are asking if there are any pre-built HTML/CSS UIs. The answer is that there are many, and they are often referred to as "UI Frameworks" or "HTML/CSS Framworks".

The most common HTML/CSS frameworks are [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) & [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), but my personal favorite is [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/).

Each framework has its own unique features and bugs, but in most cases it comes down to personal preference.